# Failed installing dependencies with cabal

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I am trying to install the dependencies for a project but I am running into this error:

```
Failed to install base-unicode-symbols-0.2.2.4 
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install: base-unicode-symbols-0.2.2.4 failed during     the final install step. 
The exception was: /tmp/pkgConf-base-unicode-symbols-0.2.25614.4: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

I am running Debian 7 with the latest Haskell-Platform built from source.

How do I fix it?
Thanks,
James

Comment: The tarball might be corrupt, does this error persist if you try `cabal install http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-unicode-symbols-0.2.2.4/base-unicode-symbols-0.2.2.4.tar.gz` ?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and after search, found this solution: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1883

To summarize, the problem can be solved by setting your locale. On linux:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

was good enough for me.

Comment: export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" (missed a dash)